@Transactional propagation and isolation levels in Spring Boot
I have a question regarding @Transactional annotation.
In our project we have a REST controller that receives events from the message bus and calls a UseCase(@Service) to save the changes to the database. Only 1 cell per 1 row.
The problem is that by receiving, let's say, 4 requests with almost no delay I lose 1 or 2 of them. For example, my entities and @Service:
public class Book {
    private UUID id;
    private String title;
    private Author author1;
    private Author author2;
    private Author author3;
    private Author author4;
}

public class Author {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}


Author is a value object and has no separate table.
public class BookDBEntity {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author1Name;
    private String author2Name;
    private String author3Name;
    private String author4Name;
    private int author1Age;
    private int author2Age;
    private int author3Age;
    private int author4Age;
}

This is my DBEntity
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public class EventSaveBookUseCase implements EventSaveBookPort {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    //Constructor

    @Override
    public void updateBook(EventUpdateBookCommand command) {

        Book book = bookRepository.getBookById(command.getBookId());

        book.setAuthor(book, command.getAuthor()); // Here I set 1 of 4 authors

        bookRepository.updateBook(book);
    }
}

And here is something similar to my service.
In my understanding I should create a new transaction and isolate it every time I use this service. But it's not the case. I sometimes lose author 1/2/3/4.
will be really grateful for your help. Thanks in advance.
I expect my transaction to be isolated in every usage of the service.

Question is unclear. You attached BookDBEntity but it is not used in code. You use in code  EventUpdateBookCommand but it is not attached. I feel you added boilerplate code and you did not add important code. Conroller code should be helpful

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
